# RESTful API Set-Cookie header is not pass with request header to back-end

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-rest, setcookie

I am using Spring project and AngularJS project. I tried to update the Set-Cookie header using AngularJS. But, that value is not set to the backend API.

I debug the backend service and checked the values which is requested through the request header Set-Cookie. The updated value was not exit.

```
myFunction: async (value1, value2, cookie) => {
        try {
            let header = null;
            if(cookie === null){
                header = {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }else{
                header = {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Set-Cookie'  : 'YES'
                }
            }

            const { data } = await $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: RestURIs.myrequest,
                headers: header,
                data: {
                    value1: value1,
                    value2: value2
                }
            });
            return data;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('error on service');
            return $q.reject(error);
        }
    }
```

If this is wrong way to update the header. how to do it ? please help me to identify the issue which I did ?.

Comment: try this: `'Set-Cookie'  : 'cookiename=YES'`

Comment: Start by inspecting the actual request in your browser dev tools network to see if what is being sent is what is expected

Comment: @Kazz thank you for your answer. it's not working. The issue is still exist. Do you have any option to solve this ?

Comment: @charlietfl I did it. In the header has 'Set-Cookie: YES', but it's not receive on back-end service. The actual scenario is, webservice response a cookie and I need to update it and send to back-end again.

Comment: Hard to help more without being able to debug back end since front end is doing what is expected. Is this a cross origin request (different domain or port)?

Comment: yes I know @charlietfl and thanks for helping me. Yes, This is a cross origin request. But, I set {response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")} o my back-end. I try to set cookie on 'Cookie' header. now i have another error. "Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie". do you have any idea about this ?